# Multithreading for Django

Tags: python, django, python-multithreading

I'm writing web application for get data from Database(MySQL) to file.csv using Django Framework.I can get data but It take so much time to get complete successfully.I don't want to wait for get data finish. I want to continue to next activity but background still get data from Database.

My setup : Python 3.6.5, Django 2.1

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is a python package that will help you perform asynchronous tasks in Django. You can refer to [First Steps With Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) for getting started. Also, I have covered a few setup issues and their solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640549/celery-async-tasks-and-periodic-tasks-together).